# How to enable animated page transitions with Phonegap + JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Per the JQuery Mobile documentation ...

> To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an
>   external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax

How, if it is even possible, can one enable page transitions when building a Phonegap application where all the pages are local rather than sitting on a web server?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference if AJAX is loading from local file or web (except if web you need to whitelist the domains).

By default Phonegap/Cordova for iOS loads from www/index.html.

Here is an example with 2 pages, with in-line data attributes for the transitions.

First page, `page1.html`

```
<!-- page1.html -->
...
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    Local on same page<br/>
    <a href="#samePage" data-transition="pop">same page</a>

    Local in another page<br/>
    <a href="page2.html" data-transition="fade">new page</a>

</div>

<div id="samePage" data-role="page">
    Same Page
</div>
...
```

A separate file `page2.html`.

```
<!-- page2.html -->
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    Page 2
</div>
```